# java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

The MainFragment pass the data to ActivityContentFragment but got the error that "java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Mainfragment

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ActivityInfo activityInfo =(ActivityInfo) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content,new ActivityContentFragment());

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("eventName",activityInfo);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);   
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });
        }
```

ActivityContentFragment

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_content, container, false);

            activityInfo= (ActivityInfo)getArguments().getSerializable("eventName");       
            Log.d("why","eventName="+ activityInfo.eventName);
        return view;

    }
```

ActivityInfo class

```
public class ActivityInfo implements Serializable {

    public String eventName;
    public String date;
    public String review;

    public String toString(){
      return this.eventName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this out —>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689889/null-object-reference-error-while-passing-a-serializable-object-to-fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

// The actual instance of the ActivityContentFragment is created here:
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content,new ActivityContentFragment());

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("eventName",activityInfo);

// This Fragment is not your ActivityContentFragment:
fragment.setArguments(bundle);   
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

You're creating an instance of `Fragment` and applying the `Bundle` to that instance. You never apply the `Bundle` to the `ActivityContentFragment` that you're actually committing.

Instead, you can use:

```
ActivityContentFragment fragment = new ActivityContentFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("eventName", activityInfo);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);   

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```